# How to COPY into one PostgreSQL table in parallel without lock?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, timescaledb, postgresql-13

As I see in `pg_stat_activiry`, only one of `COPY` command executes at once. Other queries are in Lock state as I see in `wait_event_type` column.

[image: There are only one active query at once]

How can I run several `COPY mytable FROM STDIN` in parallel without locking table?

ps. `mytable` is hypertable of TimescaleDB 2.5.0.

**UPD**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."mytable" (
    "q_time" timestamp,
    "symbol_id" int,
    "o" decimal(24,12),
    "c" decimal(24,12),
    "h" decimal(24,12),
    "l" decimal(24,12),
    "v" bigint,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_ts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (symbol_id, "q_time")
);

SELECT create_hypertable('mytable', 'q_time', 'symbol_id', 1,
  create_default_indexes => false, 
  chunk_time_interval => '7 days'::interval);
```

**UPD2**

I run in parallel next commands:

```
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "cat file01.gz | gunzip | psql -d db -U user -c "\copy mytable from stdin HEADER DELIMITER ';' CSV\"").Output()
```

TimescaleDB 2.5.0

PostgreSQL 13

max_connections = 200

max_worker_processes = 21

max_parallel_workers = 10

Comment: Plain PostgreSQL doesn't do this automatically.  Must be something you are doing, or something timescaledb is doing. Can you show how to set up the table with timescaledb?

Comment: @jjanes schema updated

Comment: Seems copy will do a full lock by default. I know Timescale also offers a tool for a parallel copy that maybe can be useful. As it's for faster ingestion, probably it overcome this issue: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy

Comment: As I see this tool just paralleled COPY to several connections like in my case. And as I see this is not worked way in my case... https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/blob/master/cmd/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go#L252-L256

Comment: If it is possible in your case to use `file_fdw` then why not attach the file as a foreign table (or a temporary foreign table in `pg_temp` schema) and then `insert into mytable ... select ... from the_foreign_table ...`? I think that this is more powerful and flexible than COPY as (almost) all SQL features are available.

Comment: @Nick curious to know what was the issue in the timescaledb-parallel-copy, was it not doing the COPY commands in parallel? Also, how many cores on your PG server?

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran 10 cores. I will try later way without psql, by advice from timescaledb's slack - `psql` may be reason of locking.